# AngularJS - Three input field phone number validation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to validate the phone number fields. Conditions are the fields gets validated once the user enter the next location name field. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/mvsyde1o/)
Also phone number fields need auto tab to the next phone input field. [on entering the area code (3 digit) focus should go on to the next 3 digit phone input field). when done focus on to the last 4 digit.

```
<form id="aidLocationForm" class="well form-inline">
    <div class="control-group phone-group">
      <label for="phone1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 control-label">Primary contact number</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="3" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="3" class="area-code input-mini aid-primary-phone1-lbl" aria-label="Primary contact number" pattern="/^[0-9]{3}$">
        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="3" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="3" class="area-code input-mini aid-primary-phone2-lbl" aria-label="Primary contact number" pattern="/^[0-9]{3}$">
        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="4" class="area-code input-mini aid-primary-phone3-lbl" aria-label="Primary contact number" pattern="/^[0-9]{4}$">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="primaryLocationName" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 control-label aid-primary-location-location-lbl">Primary Location Name</label>
      <!-- end of label -->
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="primaryLocationName" id="primaryLocationName" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 aid-primary-location-name-input" ng-model="" required placeholder="Enter the city followed by location" size="50" maxlength="50"
        aria-disabled="true" aria-label="Primary Location Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Your fiddle isn't functional.  Please post a working version.

Comment: Did you even check the console before posting? It doesn't work!

Comment: @Phix --  My bad.. i have added basic validations for checking length and added jquery.jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/mvsyde1o/

Comment: @dragonfly Hey, check out my solution and let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a directive with event handling to accomplish this.

<kbd>[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ay2gd91j/5/)</kbd>

The key changes include the following:

1) Load jQuery in your fiddle *before* angular so you get access to jQuery's selectors inside of angular functions.

2) Wrap your inputs in a container with the proper directive (Note: this can also be done with a single element with `restrict: "E"` instead of `restrict: "A"` and use the `template` property to define the child HTML)

3) Handle the `input` event on the inputs and if the length exceeds the value in the `maxlength` property, focus the next input. This is really simple with jQuery, but can be done without if you really want to.

4) There are a million ways to do validation on the inputs, but I have included a simple method.

**HTML**

```
<div phone-input>
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="3" class="area-code input-mini aid-primary-phone1-lbl" 
         aria-label="Primary contact number" pattern="^[0-9]{3}$">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="3" class="area-code input-mini aid-primary-phone2-lbl" 
         aria-label="Primary contact number" pattern="^[0-9]{3}$">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" class="area-code input-mini aid-primary-phone3-lbl" 
         aria-label="Primary contact number" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$">
</div>
```

**Angular Directive**

```
.directive("phoneInput", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      function checkForErrors(input) {
        var errors = "";
        if (!new RegExp(input.attr("pattern")).test(input.val())) {
            errors += `Field must contain ${input.attr("maxlength")} numbers!\n`;
        }
        return errors;
      }
      element.on("input", "input", function () {
        var trigger = $(this);
        if (trigger.val().length >= trigger.attr("maxlength")) {
            trigger.blur().next().focus();
        }
      });

      element.on("blur", "input", function () {
        var trigger = $(this);
        var errors = checkForErrors(trigger);
        trigger.attr("title", errors);
        if (trigger.val().trim() === "") {
            trigger.addClass("invalid-field");
            trigger.attr("title", "Field cannot be empty!");
        }
        else if (errors === "") {
          trigger.removeClass("invalid-field");
        }
        else {
          trigger.addClass("invalid-field");
          trigger.focus();
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: phone field can accept only number and when invalid should display error message. But the fiddle doesn't show any error message

Comment: @dragonfly Probably good information to update your question with. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @dragonfly Edited with validation.